# C# VS2017 Community - How to automatically ZIP the output folder of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017, zip

Does anyone know of a way easy way to automatically ZIP the Debug/Release folder after build and copy that ZIP to another folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will use 7-Zip to zip the output files to the solutions folder.

Create this zipper.bat file and place it in your solution folder:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -y -tzip %2 %1 -mx5

echo done
```

Add this line to your Post-build events:

```
call "$(SolutionDir)zipper.bat" "$(TargetDir)" "$(SolutionDir)zipped.zip"
```

Comment: But what if 7-zip is installed on another location, there must be a way to get the installation path through environment variables

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way, AFAIK, you can either use a .bat file and call it on the post-build event, or you can use a MSBuild Script or FAKE to use F# as scripting.

Comment: Thanks Nekeniehl I will try that. I also stumbled on a thing where you add C# code to the project file to zip it at the end but it does not zip the folders and subfolders..